# What special variables available in Visual Studio watch window in .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I just learned about $exception in the VS.NET watch window for .NET yesterday. This shows the current exception that has been thrown and is a big time-saver in not needing to find the little exclamation point icon and hover over it.

**What other special variables are there in the watch window?**

(Note: this question is about .NET, not C++.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Supported [Pseudovariables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx) in Visual Studio for .NET debugging:

- **$exception**: Displays information on the last exception. If no exception has occurred, evaluating `$exception` displays an error message. In Visual C# only, when the Exception Assistant is disabled, `$exception` is automatically added to the **Locals** window when an exception occurs.
- **$user**: Displays a structure with account information for the account running the application. For security reasons, the password information is not displayed.

The following only apply to Visual Basic:

- **$delete** or **$$delete**: Deletes an implicit variable that was created in the **Immediate** window. The syntax is `$delete,` *variable* or `$$delete,` *variable*.
- **$objectids** or **$listobjectids**: Displays all active Object IDs as children of the specified expression. The syntax is `$objectid,` *expression* or `$listobjectids,` *expression*.
- **$*N*#**: Displays object with Object ID equal to *N*.
- **$dynamic**: Displays the special **Dynamic View** node for an object that implements the `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`. Interface. The syntax is `$dynamic,` *object*. This feature applies only to code that uses .NET Framework version 4. See [Dynamic View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998308.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

If you right click any variable in the Watch window, you can create an *Object ID*. This will give you a number, e.g. the first object ID will be 1#.

The *Object ID* represents the specific instance. The instance can then be watched in the Watch window just like a regular variable, but you can keep watching the instance even when local reference go out of scope. When it eventually gets garbage collected you will lose access to it.

Answer (score 3):

@ERR
;Last error value,the same value returned by the GetLastError() API function

@TIB
;Thread information block for the current thread

@CLK
;Undocumented clock register; usable only in the Watch window

@EAX, @EBX, @ECX, @EDX, @ESI, @EDI, @EIP, @ESP, @EBP, @EFL
;Intel CPU registers

@CS, @DS, @ES, @SS, @FS, @GS
;Intel CPU segment registers

@ST0, @ST1, @ST2, @ST3, @ST4, @ST5, @ST6, @ST7
;Intel CPU floating-point registers

Answer (score 2):

Using "@err" will display the value of GetLastError() and "@err,hr" displays the error message.

Comment: This is from C++ land (along with @eax, @clk, and so on), but I was hoping to get more from the .NET world.

Answer (score 2):

The $user pseudo variable is the only other documented one.  In VS2010, the VB.NET debugger acquires [some new ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: The $dynamic that VB supports also works in C# via ", dynamic". Not sure about the rest, though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998308%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: I saw something else in that MSDN article.  It supports automatic dynamic view of __ComObject.  That's awesome.